# Proof of normalvector on a plane

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I found that, for the plane with linear equation: Ax + By + Cz = 0, that the vector a with coordinates: (A, B, C), is a normal vector on that plane. Where does that come from? And can someone provide a mathematical proof?

EDIT: sorry you seem to interpret my question wrong, I know that a normal vector is perpendicular to the plane. But why is a vector with coordinates (A,B,C) perpendicular to a plane with equation Ax + By + Cz = D?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's define vectors $\mathbf{x} = (x,y,z)$ and $\mathbf{n} = (a,b,c)$, and let $\mathbf{o} = (0,0,0)$ be the origin. Then we have
$$
ax+by+cz = (\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{o}) \cdot \mathbf{n}
$$
where the dot on the right denotes a vector "dot" product.
So, the equation of the plane is $(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{o}) \cdot \mathbf{n}=0$.
The dot product of two vectors is zero only when they are perpendicular. So, the equation says that the point $\mathbf{x}$ lies on the plane iff the vector $(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{o})$ is perpendicular to the vector $\mathbf{n}$. This means that $\mathbf{n}$ must be normal to the plane.

Comment: And why is (a,b,c) perpendicular to the plane?

Comment: The answer explains why $\mathbf{n}$ is normal to the plane (I hope) -- because it's perpendicular to any vector lying in the plane. And, by my definition, $\mathbf{n} = (a,b,c)$.

Comment: I edited the question, you are answering a question that I didn't meant to ask :)

Comment: Well, what I wrote is intended to answer your question (the new one -- I understood what you wanted from the start). I guess I was not successful. If a vector $\mathbf{n}$ is perpendicular to all the vectors lying in the plane (or even perpendicular to just two of them, actually), then it must be perpendicular to the plane itself.

Comment: Yes I understand that, and two vectors are perpendicular if and only if their inner product is zero. Is the ax+by+cz=(x−o)⋅n an alternative equation for describing a plane?

Comment: The equation $(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{o}) \cdot \mathbf{n} =0$ is an alternative equation for a plane. It's just in vector form, rather than coordinate form.

Answer (score 1):

If $(x,y,z)\in P$, $(x,y,z)\cdot(A,B,C) = Ax+By+Cz = 0$:
$$
P\subset \{(x,y,z) | Ax+By+Cz = 0\}
$$But as both are planes, they have the same dimension and are equal.

Answer (score 1):

By the definition of a plane, $a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0)+c(z-z_0)=0$, which is equivalent to the equation $Ax+By+Cz=0$ , the normal vector to the plane is $(a,b,c)$

Comment: Why is that so?